# PHP Overlay PNG over JPG then resize and position JPG to mask of PNG

Tags: php, image, gd

I need to take a PNG of a background and a helmet, the helmet is transparent in the middle. In PHP I will pass it top and left coordinates, and width and height of the JPG. I want to take the JPG and put it underneath the PNG, make it the size that I send it (resize bigger or smaller to what ever size I give it), place it at X and Y underneath the PNG and make the PNG front most. In otherwords what ever part of the JPG is outside the PNG border's gets cut out and the resulting image is the PNG overlaid on the JPG at the PNG width and height.

This is what I currently have, but it's just saving the helmet with a black background where the head should be.

```
$photo1 = imagecreatefromjpeg($_POST['photo']);
    $foto1W = imagesx($photo1);
    $foto1H = imagesy($photo1);
    $photoFrameW = $res['width'];
    $photoFrameH = $res['height'];
    $photoFrame = imagecreatetruecolor($photoFrameW,$photoFrameH);
    imagecopyresampled($photoFrame, $photo1, 0, 0, 0, 0, $photoFrameW, $photoFrameH, $foto1W, $foto1H);

    $photo2 = imagecreatefrompng('images/casco.png');
    $foto2W = imagesx($photo2);
    $foto2H = imagesy($photo2);
    $photoFrame2W = '500';
    $photoFrame2H = '556';

    $photoFrame2    = imagecreatetruecolor($photoFrame2W,$photoFrame2H);
    $trans_colour   = imagecolorallocatealpha($photoFrame2, 0, 0, 0, 127);
    imagefill($photoFrame2, 0, 0, $trans_colour);

    imagecopyresampled($photoFrame2, $photo2, 0, 0, 0, 0, $photoFrame2W, $photoFrame2H, $foto2W, $foto2H);

    imagecopy($photoFrame2, $photoFrame, $res['left']+556, $res['top'], 0, 0, imagesx($photoFrame), imagesy($photoFrame));

    imagejpeg($photoFrame2, "fb_images/$codigo2.jpg");
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Can you post some example images to help us understand what you are doing?  Can you show us your source code thus far?

Comment: This is what I am trying to do with PHP: 
http://i.imgur.com/FsoQt.jpg

I have not tried any code so far, as imagecopy and imagejpeg and all those are funky and I don't totally understand them at times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself using the above as a starting point. Problem was two fold, it was placing the wrong image on top and I wasn't using the right place to re-position the image. I ended up re-sizing and re-positioning the image before insertion. Then just inserted the PNG on top of the JPG at the end.

```
    $photo1 = imagecreatefromjpeg($_POST['photo']);
    $foto1W = imagesx($photo1);
    $foto1H = imagesy($photo1);
    $photoFrameW = $res['width'];
    $photoFrameH = $res['height'];
    $photoFrame = imagecreatetruecolor(500,556);
    imagecopyresampled($photoFrame, $photo1, $res['left'], $res['top']+556, 0, 0, $photoFrameW, $photoFrameH, $foto1W, $foto1H);

    $photo2 = imagecreatefrompng('images/casco.png');
    $foto2W = imagesx($photo2);
    $foto2H = imagesy($photo2);
    $photoFrame2W = '500';
    $photoFrame2H = '556';

    $photoFrame2    = imagecreatetruecolor($photoFrame2W,$photoFrame2H);
    $trans_colour   = imagecolorallocatealpha($photoFrame2, 0, 0, 0, 127);
    imagefill($photoFrame2, 0, 0, $trans_colour);

    imagecopyresampled($photoFrame2, $photo2, 0, 0, 0, 0, $photoFrame2W, $photoFrame2H, $foto2W, $foto2H);

    imagecopy($photoFrame, $photoFrame2, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($photoFrame2), imagesy($photoFrame2));

    imagejpeg($photoFrame, "fb_images/$codigo2.jpg");
```